# Image of line under Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

The question states to calculate the image of the line $\{\text{Re}(z)=c\}$ under the Mobius transformation $z\mapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}$. For $c=1$, it can be shown that the line is invariant under the transformation (in the extended real sense, i.e. $1\mapsto \infty$ and $\infty\mapsto 1$. For $c\neq1$, I have a hint saying that the image is a circle, but I am having trouble understanding what is going on. We know that 
$$
c+iv\mapsto\frac{c+1+iv}{c-1+iv}=\frac{(c+1+iv)(c-1-vi)}{(c-1)^2+v^2}
$$
but I do not see how the result can be shown to lie on a circle of some sort. Is there a better way of approaching this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every non-singular Möbius transformation maps circles and lines to circles and lines. Equivalently, circles on the Riemann sphere are maps to other such circles. That does not mean that circles are mapped to circles or lines are mapped to lines.

For $c\ne 1$, the line where $-\infty < v < \infty$ is mapped under
$$
             c+iv \mapsto \frac{c+1+iv}{c-1+iv}
$$
to a circle in the complex plane. It cannot be mapped to a line because the point at $\infty$ is not in the image. The image is symmetric about the real axis, $c+i0$ is mapped to $\frac{c+1}{c-1}$, and $c\pm i\infty$ is mapped to $1$. So the center of the circle should be $\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{c+1}{c-1})=\frac{c}{c-1}$. To verify,
\begin{align}
   \left|\frac{c+1+iv}{c-1+iv}-\frac{c}{c-1}\right|&=\left|\frac{c^2-1+iv(c-1)-c(c-1)-icv}{(c-1)(c-1+iv)}\right| \\
     &=\left|\frac{c-1-iv}{(c-1)(c-1+iv)}\right| \\
     &=\left|\frac{1}{c-1}\right|.
\end{align}
So the radius of the circle is given on the right, and you can see the above does define a circle in the complex plane.

Comment: But $1$ isn't in that circle...

Comment: @Mauro : Where do you see that I said it was? I've given you the two points on the circle which also lie on the real axis. Those points were correctly stated to be $-1$ and $\frac{c+1}{c-1}$. The average of these two is the center of the circle, which is $\frac{1}{c-1}$, and I've shown you that you do get a circle with radius $|c|/|c-1|$.

Comment: But $1$ must be in the circle, since $\infty \mapsto 1$.

Comment: @Mauro : I miscopied the problem. Thanks. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, $\infty \mapsto 1$, and you can see that $c\mapsto \frac{c+1}{c-1}$. A Moebius transformation takes a circle to a circle or a line, but you can see that $c+i$ goes to a point outside the real line, so in this case it will be a circle.

Also, this Moebius transformation has real coefficients, so it maps the real line into itself. Since it preserves angles, and the angle between the real line and $\{\text{Re}(z)=c\}$ is a right angle, the circle our line is mapped to must also be perpendicular to the real line. This means that $1$ and $\frac{c+1}{c-1}$ lie in a diameter of the circle, and so its center must be $\frac{1 + \frac{c+1}{c-1}}{2}$, and you can easily find its radius after that.